# ios loop for asynchronous requests

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

I have to make multiple http requests asynchronously (one request at a time). For looping I am doing this:

```
-(void) Foo1
{
    [makerequest];
}

-(void) requestCompletes
{
   //Do something
   [self Foo1:[array objectAtIndex:i++]];
}

viewDidLoad
{
         [self Foo1:[array objectAtIndex:0]];
}
```

But looping in the completion-handler doesn't seems a good idea to me. Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not the correct way. The iOS platform has a [NSOperationQueue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592) class, which allows you to schedule operations. By creating you're own subclass of any of the operations ([NSInvocationOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSInvocationOperation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005505), [NSBlockOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSBlockOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008157) or the [NSOperation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html)) and using it to wrap around a [NSURLRequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003762) you can easily add and execute web request by calling

```
[operationQueue addOperation:requestOperation];
```